# How to stop the server in a multithreaded client/server application?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

How do I get out of the while-loop?

Variable "running" is set TRUE by default and by receiving "shutdown" the value should be changed to FALSE and exit the Thread (the run-method). So the server gets closed after the while-loop.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        while (running) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            executor.execute(new Handler(socket,server));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        server.close();
```

The run-method:

```
while(Server.getRunning()){
            System.out.println("..Wait for Input!");

            String inline = input.readLine();
            String[] a = inline.split(" ");

            int result;

            if (a[0].equals("shutdown")){
                Server.setRunning(false);
                Protocol.status(client, "shutdown");
                return;
            } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide section where you define and control variable `running`

Comment: Also, note the following about `Socket accept()`:
`Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.`

Comment: running is a global static variable in my Server.class and for controlling the variable I use getter/setter-method. when the client delivers "shutdown" the client is closed fine, but the server reacts only when I connect a new client, because of the server.accept() in the while-loop

Comment: Set `running` to false, then [`interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) the thread that is blocking.

Comment: already tried it with `interrupt` .. but the loop always goes one step further

Comment: Is your `running` variable declared as volatile?

Comment: no, but I think this wouldn't make any differences, because my problem is that I am stuck in the accept() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you wrap your loop in try-catch for `SocketException` and implement something like this:

```
public synchronized void shutdown()
{
   this.running = false;
   this.server.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks. i tried it with this method, but this way is too radically. I just want to get back from the run-method to my while-loop. there i want to close the executor and the close the server too

Comment: I'm not aware about any other proper way to interrupt `accept()` method, which is blocking your loop.